# Split \xef\xbb\xbf in a list read from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, stop-words

I tried to read big data file.txt and split all the comma, point, etc, so I read the file with this code in Python:

```
file= open("file.txt","r")
importantWords =[]
for i in file.readlines():
    line = i[:-1].split(" ")
    for word in line:
        for j in word:
            word = re.sub('[\!@#$%^&*-/,.;:]','',word)
            word.lower()
        if word not in stopwords.words('spanish'):
            importantWords.append(word)
print importantWords
```

and it printed `['\xef\xbb\xbfdataText1', 'dataText2' .. 'dataTextn']`.

How can I clean that `\xef\xbb\xbf`?  I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Did you bother searching for that particular string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [UTF-8 encoded BOM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode).

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.BOM_UTF8
'\xef\xbb\xbf'
```

You can  use [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) with [`encoding='utf-8-sig'`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) to skip the BOM sequence:

```
with codecs.open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

SIDENOTE: Instead of using `file.readlines`, just iterate over the file. `file.readlines` will create unnecessary temporary list if what you want is just iterate over the file.

Comment: For Python 2.7 and higher, `io.open` is usually superior to `codecs.open` (it's faster and usually more correct; e.g. `codecs.open` doesn't do line ending conversions).